# HTML5 Video API: Cannot Pause On Last Frame If Looping Enabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video, html5-video

Trying to pause a video on the very last frame appears to not work if the video is on the very last frame.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

})

app.directive('someVideo', function ($window, $timeout) {
    return {
       controller: function($scope) {
        
        },
        link: function (scope, elm) {
            scope.videoPlayer = elm[0];
            scope.keyDownEvent = keyDownEvent;
            scope.currentTime = 0;
            scope.videoPlayer.loop = true;
            
            angular.element($window).bind('keydown',scope.keyDownEvent);
            
            function keyDownEvent(e){
            console.log(e.keyCode);
               switch(e.keyCode) {
                    case 32: //space
                     scope.videoPlayer.loop = !scope.videoPlayer.loop;
                     console.log('spcae: ',scope.videoPlayer.loop);
                      break;
                  case 38: //up
                  scope.videoPlayer.currentTime = 0;
                      console.log('up: ', scope.videoPlayer.currentTime);
           break;
                  case 40: //down
                      scope.videoPlayer.pause();
           scope.videoPlayer.currentTime = scope.videoPlayer.duration;
                      console.log('down: ', scope.videoPlayer.currentTime);
           break;
               }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <video some-video src="http://nagi.ca/u/google.mp4" autoplay></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4bygou77/4/

**STEPS TO REPO:**
1) launch the fiddle and click the video to set focus
2) use keys: space = toggle loop, down = last frame, up = first frame

**RESULTS:**
With Loop Enabled: video pauses, jumps to last frame, then jumps to first frame
With Loop Disabled: video pauses, jumps to last frame (*My Desired Result*)

Comment: ummm ...disable loop??

Comment: Goal is to build external controls which have a toggle for loop on/off, if I go this route, will have to keep track of loop being previously on if the user then jumps to the beginning of the video and then re-enable it. Trying to avoid workarounds like this if there is a more succinct solution.

Comment: well that wasn't spelled out in the question

Comment: why not set loop after you set currentTime? there doesn't appear to be a need for a specific order, since the changes fire at once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
scope.videoPlayer.currentTime = scope.videoPlayer.duration;
```

to this

```
scope.videoPlayer.currentTime = scope.videoPlayer.duration - 1;
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/4bygou77/5/

Comment: Tried this out (instead of -1, I did -framesPerSecond), and totally worked as expected. Was not 100% accurate because not last frame, but definitely a viable solution. Thank you for the help! 

I ended up just having to turn loop off, which was what I was originally trying to avoid (not a big prob though :) ). Basically API does not seem to like going to last frame while loop is enabled.