# HTML5 Video - Pause at the Last Frame

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html, video

I'm using a full background HTML5 video for the header of my Wordpress website and would like it to freeze at the last frame of the video, instead of cutting to a black background as it's doing currently.

```
if(strpos($video_image, "http://") !== false || strpos($video_image, "https://") !== false){
            $video_image_src = $video_image;
        } else {
            $video_image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($video_image, 'full');
            $video_image_src = $video_image_src[0];
        }

        //$poster_markup = (!empty($video_image)) ? 'poster="'.$video_image_src.'"' : null ;
        $poster_markup = null;
        $video_markup = null;

        $video_markup .=  '<div class="video-color-overlay" data-color="'.$bg_color.'"></div>';


        $video_markup .= '

        <div class="mobile-video-image" style="background-image: url('.$video_image_src.')"></div>
        <div class="nectar-video-wrap" data-bg-alignment="'.$bg_position.'">


            <video class="nectar-video-bg" width="1800" height="700" '.$poster_markup.'  preload="auto" autoplay>';
                if(!empty($video_webm)) { $video_markup .= '<source type="video/webm" src="'.$video_webm.'">'; }
                if(!empty($video_mp4)) { $video_markup .= '<source type="video/mp4" src="'.$video_mp4.'">'; }
                if(!empty($video_ogv)) { $video_markup .= '<source type="video/ogg" src="'. $video_ogv.'">'; }

           $video_markup .='</video>

        </div>';

        echo $video_markup;
    }
```

In the video class I've already removed the loop that was there, that's left me with the video going directly to a black screen once it ends.

Any help on how to get it to pause on the last frame would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video API: Cannot Pause On Last Frame If Looping Enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209077/html5-video-api-cannot-pause-on-last-frame-if-looping-enabled)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that other question, mine involves PHP and that is a Javascript explanation that I don't understand.

Comment: That's why it says possible, I was hoping it would have helped you.

Comment: this isn't a PHP issue, it's a Javascript problem (once the page is loaded you're controlling the video from JS, not PHP). Does your video have a black frame at the end, because looking at a quick sample I have, it ends showing whatever the last frame on the video is

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.

Yeah, after I looked into it more I realised that it's a javascript issue. The video has no black frame at the end. It's actually now working on Safari but not Chrome & Firefox :/... 

Maybe if I upload the JS file someone might have a solution? Although I have raised a ticket with the Wordpress support group and they're looking into it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a 1.01 minute video which ends in black. To make it end before it goes black, set the time lime to 1.00 minute. To do this append "#t=0,60" to the end of the video.

```
<video controls width="450" > <source src="https://math.hawaii.edu/~dale/140/camtasia/07m1.mp4#t=0,60" type="video/mp4"> </video>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is the `#t=0,60` standardized or documented somewhere?